# What is happening in my Bash code?

Tags: linux, bash

When I want to display my calendar on the screen, the script is showing me an error on the conditional — if else — but I don't know why; I suppose it should be ok.

```
# !/bin/bash
rm --f calen
mostrar = 0
echo "agrega un mes"
read mes
echo "agrega un año"
read year
echo "Agregar [1] para mostrar las dos primeras semanas, o [2] para mostrar las ultimas dos semanas"
read mostrar
if[$mostrar = 1]  then
    cal -m $mes $year >> calen
    head -n 4 calen
else
    cal -m $mes $year >> calen
    head -n 2 calen
    tail -n 3 calen
fi
```

Comment: Did you try `if[$mostrar = 1]; then`  - with the semi-colon ?

Comment: yes, but I dont know why if change if[ $mostrar = 1 ] works

Comment: Please give more meaningful subject like "if statement not working in bash"

Comment: Note that the shebang on the first line needs to start `#!` with no space between the `#` and the `!`.  It will mostly work, until you start using features of Bash that are not recognized by `sh`, which is what will be used to run the code as written with `# !/bin/bash` (because the space prevents what's intended to be the shebang from being a shebang).  You need to get very careful with spacing very quickly — spaces matter a lot in shell scripting (both where they are and where they are not).

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net), it automatically detects issues like this

Answer (score 4):

Assuming (just for the sake of example) that `mostrar` is `0`, then this line:

```
if[$mostrar = 1]  then
```

means "run the command `if[0` with the arguments `=`, `1]`, and `then`". Since you don't have a command named `if[0`, this blows up.

You can fix most of this by adding whitespace around the various components of the command. Additionally, you need a semicolon or line-break before the `then`, and *should* wrap the `$mostrar` expansion in double-quotes to prevent filename-expansion and word splitting (both of which can lead to bizarre results). So:

```
if [ "$mostrar" = 1 ] ; then
```